# Location from ip address

Tags: ip-address

Do you know of any service which given an ip address it returns a location/country?
I found a few lists we can add to our database but do I need to update them often? Is there any rule (like telephone numbers) to know the country of origin?

Sorry, I know this might sound a stupid question but for what we're doing it can't fail.

EDIT: I forgot to mention this has to be accessible programmatically (PHP)

Thanks :)
Diogo

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a tool to use in developing an app rather than an existing web app with an interface for humans. Such a question would be better on http://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.farhad.ca/2011/06/15/rbl-based-ip-to-location/

Assume IP address of question is 10.11.12.13, then here is a sample:

```
<?php

$ip_address = gethostbyname('13.12.11.10.rbloc.dayanadns.com');
list($d1,$d2,$d3,$d4) = explode('.',$ip_address);
$country_code = chr($d3).chr($d4);

print "Result address: ".$ip_address."\n";
print "Country code: ".$country_code."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) also has a service. We use the free csv download from this service so that the lookup is on our local system.
Find full information on how to use it in this [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server/67215/) article.

Answer (score 2):

GeoIP lookups are generally done using a commercial service. IP address ranges do change, so there is no canonical database.

There are also lots of strange outliers - IP ranges assigned to airlines, for instance, or those assigned to the US military, who may be anywhere in the world.

In the Entertainment indsutry, where rights holders (movie studios, record labels) own regional rights to content, the use of one of a number of approved commercial services is often a contractual obligation. I know from experience that MaxMind have a great service. Google "geoip lookup" and you'll get enough options.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll do a search as you said :)

Comment: Do you know if an an ip jump countries? Thanks

Comment: Just seen this article on the Register about the sale of an IPv4 block. Seems that we're now in the dying days of IPv4, so some pretty strange things may start to happen to IP addresses. All the more reason to use a commercial service, as it's unlikely that free datasets will keep up to date with this sort of thing.

Comment: Thank you, does anyone know if there are already any good services for IPv6?

Answer (score 2):

[Geo IP Tool](http://www.geoiptool.com/) is doing what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

I use http://www.hostip.info/ in my site, which provides a web service lookup to resolve the IP to an address.

Implementation is very easy (in .NET and likely PHP, JAVA).  Unfortunately, it only resolves about 1/2 the time...so the rest of the time I have to use another service to resolve it.

BUT IT IS FREE.

For paid services, MelissaData offers a good quality service...but you have to pay if you do processing in volume.

I personally wish Google offered a service to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a service I found with an API.
Everything explained here: http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php