# how to determine location based on ip

Tags: geolocation, ip

how do one determine location based on ip?  I'm not asking for any product or service, but rather how to go about implementing it technically.  
The ip to country is a rather static mapping.  What about more specific locations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location from ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095784/location-from-ip-address)

Answer (score 3):

[geobyte](http://www.geobytes.com/iplocator.htm) is a good service to locate ip address. If you are thinking about an *algorithm* to find location based on IP, I think there is none. It is basically a database look up and you will retrieve the location based on the IP address.

Comment: how does one gather such database?

Comment: It is maintained by an organization. It is a big database. If you can sort out just Russia IP address, you wont think about moving to another country. It is big and probably not organized as such as you can apply an algorithm.

Comment: which organization maintains it?

Comment: There is no one organization. It is a distributed network and they all communicate with each other. There are 13 root servers, 10 in US, the other 3 in Japan, UK and Sweden. They are most operated by private and commercial organizations. http://compnetworking.about.com/od/dns_domainnamesystem/f/dns_servers.htm

Comment: I live in Italy, Bergamo, a city at 45 km from Milan. My ISP is Tiscali. This service reports 'Alaska' ...