# Get current time and date using PHP

Tags: php, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to determine location based on ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337692/how-to-determine-location-based-on-ip)

Is there a PHP function that will return the time and date no matter where the vistor is from.

Would it be able to recognise where the vistor is from and grab the time and date?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php - Check the docs first

Comment: No it won't recognise where the visitor is from: you have to tell it that yourself

Comment: As for the clients time you could get a simple table of IPs/geographic locations and go from there

Comment: You would just be better off using gmt on the server and using javascript to generate the date formats.

Comment: Can PHP not use the date function from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php? Will this work worldwide?

Comment: You can use the date() function, but it doesn't recognise the timezone of the visitor client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for php (server side) to know the client's time zone. This information is available to client side technologies like javascript.

This could help you: https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect

It will store the client's time and timezone in a cookie which is then accessible through php.