# Show location on map by IP address in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with user information (including IP Address) and I was wondering if it's possible to show the users location on a world map by getting the IP from the database in php?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: see link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337692/how-to-determine-location-based-on-ip

Answer (score 2):

To view the IP address of a visitor to your site, insert this code in the area where you want it to appear.
echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
You can then use the API to locate your GeoLite MaxMind visitor
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to associate an IP address with a physical location, but only loosely. IP addresses are not registered to an individual user's exact location. You will be finding the location of the administrative domain of an IP address...but still on a world map that should be good enough.

Basically it works like this. You get a tool called `geoip` that should come packaged with a tool called `geoiplookup`. You then go to http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ to download GeoLiteCity.dat. Then you run this command.

```
geoiplookup -f /path/to/GeoLiteCity.dat <target IP or hostname>
```

For example, just now I ran

```
geoiplookup -f ~/Downloads/GeoLiteCity.dat stackoverflow.com
```

and I got this output

```
GeoIP City Edition, Rev 1: US, CA, California, San Francisco, 94107, 37.769699, -122.393303, 807, 415
```

Using this from PHP should be easy using the built in `exec` function from you PHP script.

Comment: Thank you :) But how would I then get this information to be shown on a map?

Comment: Well you could parse the string to read San Francisco, CA 94107 to get a postal style address, or you could parse the string to read 37.769699 degrees North 122.393303 degrees West. In either case you take that data and use a map API like the [Google Maps API](https://www.google.com/work/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=2016-Geo-NA-LCS-GEO-MAB-ProjectEndorHASe&utm_content=NA_generic&gclid=Cj0KEQiA6bq2BRC6ppf0_83Z1YIBEiQAgPYNvbHF1Lp_cG0rP-1UmI69pJp-UyJvNjGvB8JqOkfs3EkaAnx-8P8HAQ) and plot the position.

Comment: @JonnyUK Forgot to tag you in my comment but I replied.