# How can i find location and ip adress of users registering on my website?

Tags: asp.net, ip-address

How can i find location and ip adress of users registering on my website?

am developing a asp.net website

Comment: [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx). Location you'll probably need to look up from an IP geolocation database, or you can try and get it from HTML5 location APIs and post that to your server.

Answer (score 2):

The [`HttpRequest.UserHostAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) property contains the IP address of the remote client.

**Update:** and [here's a question that relates to the location aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095784/location-from-ip-address). (Thank you for the link, Joe!)

Comment: And a question like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095784/location-from-ip-address relates to the location aspect.